# What unexplained or difficult to explain phenomena in our universe could be used to power magic in a parallel universe?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, universe

*In the land of the Kahvoren the Entrancement of Genud Before Repentance dance to the ancient tunes of frenzy and death. With cries splitting the sky the Kahvoren circle the Chosen, the noble born bred to pass into darkness - such are war and peace preserved.  Kneeling before Genud, Nokra, chief of the tribes of the Greater Valley awaited the blessing of power and wisdom that would come with the transference of life from them... to him. As the madness of the dance begins to beat with the pulse of the dancers, the Chosen writhe in glory and exultation. "For Life!" they scream as the Kahvoren as one cry to the heavens for Genud to empower Nokra! With a scream heard above the devastating peal of thunder that concluded the Rite, the Chosen fall silent, having passed into memory — and Nokra rises, bursting with the power of a living god.*

Except that isn't what actually happened...

Oh, the Chosen are dead. Dead as doornails. But their deaths had nothing at all to do with Nokra's newfound power. They simply died because of it. They were in the way of something they didn't really understand.

Magic in this universe is as visceral as a UFC fighter's kick in our world. But the *power,* the *energy,* that makes magic what it is — *isn't natural to this universe.* The peoples of this universe don't realize it, but they're actually robbing *our universe* of...

*...something.*

**Question:** What unexplained or difficult to explain phenomena in our universe could be used to power magic in the parallel universe?

A valid answer must:

- Identify an observed event, condition, or behavior of our universe. This should be accompanied by an appropriate link/citation where details about said event, condition, or behavior can be found.
- From the perspective of suspension-of-disbelief, we should be able to consider the above event, condition, or behavior and say to ourselves either (a) there isn't enough energy in the universe to explain that or (b) the energy in the universe should let the phenomena happen, but it isn't. (Reasonable variations or interpretations of this condition are permitted, so long as the reader can believe that something doesn't make sense because there isn't enough or should be more energy of one kind or another.)
- The solution must present the condition of energy leaving our universe. ***How,*** is ***not*** contemplated by this question. Only the identification of a phenomena that could explain it.
- Answers are expected to reflect the spirit of Isaac Asimov's famous statement: "The most exciting phrase to hear in science, the one that heralds new discoveries, is not “Eureka” but 'That’s funny...'."
- Anyone who tries to insist that this is an unreasonable question because it doesn't reflect the exactitude of science as we understand it today will be crushed by their enemies, driven before their high school bullies, and lamented by their significant others.

*Note: I've included both the [science-based](/questions/tagged/science-based) and [science-fiction](/questions/tagged/science-fiction) tags because there appears to be nothing in between. Frankly, I've never been particularly happy with the wiki for [science-fiction](/questions/tagged/science-fiction). A Meta question inviting a review of its intent might be in order. Anyway, the idea here is to use science to rationalize a fictional condition. The goal is suspension-of-disbelief.*

Comment: List of unsolved problems in [physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_physics), in [astronomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_astronomy), in [chemistry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_chemistry), [and so on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_unsolved_problems).

Answer (score 2):

With this question finally someone has found a better explanation for the phenomena labelled under [dark matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter)!

> Primary evidence for dark matter comes from calculations showing that many galaxies would fly apart, or that they would not have formed or would not move as they do, if they did not contain a large amount of unseen matter.
>
> Other lines of evidence include observations in gravitational lensing and in the cosmic microwave background, along with astronomical observations of the observable universe's current structure, the formation and evolution of galaxies, mass location during galactic collisions, and the motion of galaxies within galaxy clusters.
>
> Although the existence of dark matter is generally accepted by the scientific community, some astrophysicists, intrigued by certain observations which do not fit some dark matter theories, argue ...

Those scoundrels are robbing our universe of kinetic energy which could be better used to have our galaxies fly apart!

P.S. I expect an invitation for when you will retire your (Ig)Nobel prize, I have heard good things about their buffet...